# Как сделать смену табов по переходу на якорные ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть страница с неким содержимым, которая реализована так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию на кнопки слева меняется содержимое блоков размещённых справа.
Делается это при помощи кода:

```
$('ul.tabs__caption').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
        $(this)
            .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
      .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
   
  });
  
  $('.tabs-item').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active-ter')
  
    

  });
```

Как выглядит вывод на странице:

```
<div id="service-1" class="tabs__content tabs__content-service active">
  Содержимое блока
</div>
```

Меню:

```
<ul class="tabs__caption tabs__caption-service">
    <li class="tabs-item  active "><div class="tabs-item__num">01</div>  Инженерно-геодезические изыскания</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">02</div>  Инженерно-геологические изыскания</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">03 </div> Инженерно-экологические изыскания</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">04</div>  Инженерно-гидрометеорологические изыскания</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">05</div>  Обследование зданий и сооружений</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">06</div>  Прохождение гос. и не гос. экспертизы</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">07</div>  Разработка проектной и рабочей документации</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">08</div>  Согласование проектов во всех заинтересованных инстанциях</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">09</div>  Сбор исходно-разрешительной документации</li>
    <li class="tabs-item"><div class="tabs-item__num">10</div>  Авторский и технический надзор</li>
</ul>
```

Всё в общем то работает так, как требуется, но мне необходимо ещё, что-бы к каждой кнопке был так же привязан текстовый анкор для ссылки.
Например при переходе по ссылке: `site.ru/service/#service3` открывалась страница уже с выбранным блоком номер 3. И так для всех блоков.
И так же по нажатию на каждую из ссылок этот текстовый анкор был в ссылке.

Если есть просто готовые решения для подобных задач, как допустим для слайдеров есть Swiper, буду рад просто ссылке. Это уже будет для меня решением. Главное, что-бы поддерживалось как раз создание этих самых текстовых анкоров и переход по ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вы должны определить, является ли ссылка переходом по якорю.

Допустим таким образом

```
// location.href = 'site.ru/service/#service3'
let url = location.href.split('#')[1];
// location.href - вернёт нам строку с адресом страницы
// Мы поделим её по символу '#' взяв второй элемент массива, тем самым мы получим
// url = service3; Если же поделить не получится, то мы ничего не получим
```

Далее делаем проверку, ну и вешаем класс на активный

```
let el = $('#'+url); // в нашем случае $('#service3')
if(el.length > 0) { // Если такой элемент существует, то
  el.addClass('active'); // Добавляем ему класс
}
```